Audit file system does not log to eventlog
We are investigating an issue on our system about some files are missing(potentially deleted).
I search around on internet. It seems the standard apporoach is to open the file system audit then I should see the delete action record in eventlog.
So I adjusted the group policy

And add advanced security setting to Pictures folder for test


After applied above, I deleted some images from the folder but no entry related is log into eventlog.

Not sure if I missed anything.
Or will IT's policy overwrite my setting? If that's the case, wouldn't it popup some warning and prevent my setting to be saved?
I'm using Windows 10 enterprise 22H2.

Did you reboot after changing the settings? Have you checked group policy hasn't over-written your settings?

It applied after reboot, thanks
